# Option values inside a select with React

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I'm noobie on React and I want to fill a `<select>`

The problem that I have is when I want to click one of my items... dropdown **only show different options if I put my items harcoded**. Here's my code

**Parent component**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Country from "./Country";
const CountriesList = ({ handleOnChange }) => {
  const [countriesLoaded, setCountriesLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [countriesList, setCountriesList] = useState([]);

  const getCountries = async () => {
    const api = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";
    const response = await fetch(api);
    const countrieslst = await response.json();
    setCountriesList(countrieslst);
    setCountriesLoaded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, [countriesList]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <select id="country" name="country" onChange={handleOnChange}>
        <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>

        {countriesLoaded
          ? countriesList.map((country) => (
              <Country key={country.alpha2Code} countryItem={country} />
            ))
          : null}
      </select>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default CountriesList;
```

**child component**

```
import React from "react";
const Country = ({ country }) => {
  return <option value={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</option>;
};
export default Country;
```

*If I check DOM it's ok but only shows my first option*

[image]

Thnx 4 support and have a nice day!

Comment: So what happens when you click the drop down menu? It doesn't open up? Can you share a Code Sandbox link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-rhodes-9iwxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit]
just add       <select id="country" name="country" onChange={handleOnChange} **style={{display: 'block'}}**> in your code. you will be able to view a select box rendering data

here is the link i made few changes in your code as well but this is optional:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/nd58i?file=/src/components/Form.jsx

Comment: Why? It seems perfectly acceptable to separate their logic like this if they want to. If you believe this will fix their problem could you explain *why* in your answer?

Comment: I think the problem is in my data... I'm making an API request and probably my component info load late

Comment: i am not sure about behind the scene exact logic.  But in if you are rendering option in other component it is not going to work for sure.  | i have a thinking like though syntax wise it may look correct but select box is expecting options to render and you have provided a custom component that is not resolved correctly. it's like  
<select>
<option></option>
<customComponent>
</select> 
that's why only 1st one is shown.

Comment: It has sense for me but, what would I fixed this? shall I load my whole component (CountriesList.jsx) until my API request has been finished?

Comment: it's not related to API. it's select box functionally that need to be corrected. simply follow/refer the code that i wrote. Add the option loop directly inside select box instead of rendering it via a custom component.

Comment: could you share a sandbox? or refer to this sandbox may be it will be of little help to cross check code render method 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-box-with-onchange-forked-qeigm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233339/discussion-between-antonio-labra-and-logicblower).

Comment: *expecting options to render and you have provided a custom component that is not resolved correctly* This isn't how it works.

Comment: *html node* this also isn't correct. Everything in React is JSX, which is a JavaScript syntax for making function calls to `React.createElement`. None of the JSX will make it to the DOM, so having a custom component in between the `select` and `option` will not matter.

Comment: You could try your solution in my code but it won't work :c

Comment: @AntonioLabra try the new suggestion | i updated answer

Comment: Thnx it's a design topic because I'm using materialize in my project but thank you so much for your time